# Parsing nested array of unknown depth

Tags: php, json

I am getting json files from a third party with variable depths of key:value pairs similar to this:
*** Edited JSON to clarify tablenames which will be used in mysql db.  KEY's are columns in the tables, Values are data.  The column names will be static from json to json.

```
   {                         
   "Key1": "Value1",  //non-nested key:value go to default table                     
   "Key2": "Value2",                      
   "Key3": "Value3",                                 
   "Table1": [],                      
   "Table2": [{                      
        "Key1": "Value1",                  
        "Key2": "Value2",                  
        "Key3": "Value3"},

        {"Key1": "Value1",                  
         "Key2": "Value2",                  
         "Key3": "Value3"}],

    "Table3": [
          {"Key1": "Value1",                  
            "Key2": "Value2",                  
            "Key3": "Value3"},
             {"Table4": [
                   {"Key1": "Value1",              
                    "Key2": "Value2",              
                    "Key3": "Value3"},
                {"Table5": [
                           {"Key1": "Value1",          
                            "Key2": "Value2",          
                            "Key3": "Value3"}]
                 }]
           }]    
     }
```

** This example passes JSON validation

For the intial Key:Value pairs (not in a nested array) I need to set a tablename, insert all the non-nested values into the table.  For the nested Key:Value pairs, the tablename needs to be set to the Array key, i.e. Array1, Array2, Array3, etc. where the nested Key is the column name and Value is the data.

I have been trying to reiterate the array using RecursiveIteratorIterator (I understand there are some speed advantages to this over nested foreach processing of the array) but either way.. I'm having trouble separating the nested arrays and pulling out the underlying Key:Value.

I'm trying this:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($data1),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value){
        if (!is_array($value)){
        //echo $key." KEY is not an array <br>";
        }

        if(is_array($value)){
            //echo $key." KEY is an array <br>";
                foreach($value as $key1=>$val1){
                    if (is_array($val1)){
                    //echo $key1."KEY 1 is an array<br>";  
                }
            }    
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

User @olibiaz proposed a solution that is almost 100% correct:

```
function toto(array $input, $tableName = '')
{
    foreach ($input as $key => $element) {
      if (is_array($element)) {
         toto($element, $key);
      } else {
          if ($tableName === '') {
             // here is the non nested elelement,
             // you can choose the tableName you want
             $tableName = 'NonNestedTableName';
          }
          // place your insert here or whatever you want
          // here, the tablename is the index of the nested array
          echo "TableName: $tableName, Key: $key, Data: $element \n";
      }
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get when running the above code on my JSON data:

```
TableName: project, Key: Key1, Data: Value1 // "project" used for non-nested
TableName: project, Key: Key2, Data: Value2 
TableName: project, Key: Key3, Data: Value3
TableName: 0, Key: Key1, Data: Value1  // Tablename needs to be "Array2"
TableName: 0, Key: Key2, Data: Value2  // for these 3 data sets
TableName: 0, Key: Key3, Data: Value3 
TableName: 1, Key: Key1, Data: Value1  // Tablename needs to be "Array2"
TableName: 1, Key: Key2, Data: Value2 
TableName: 1, Key: Key3, Data: Value3 
TableName: 0, Key: Key1, Data: Value1  // Tablename needs to be "Array3"
TableName: 0, Key: Key2, Data: Value2 
TableName: 0, Key: Key3, Data: Value3  
TableName: 0, Key: Key1, Data: Value1  // Tablename needs to be "Array4"
TableName: 0, Key: Key2, Data: Value2 
TableName: 0, Key: Key3, Data: Value3 
TableName: 0, Key: Key1, Data: Value1  // Tablename needs to be "Array5"
TableName: 0, Key: Key2, Data: Value2 
TableName: 0, Key: Key3, Data: Value3
```

However, instead of using the numerical index for table name, I need to use the Key name for the array. Perhaps olibiaz or another user has a suggestion as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: Your JSON is missing commas in several places and the indentation is inconsistent. Can you please fix it so that we can understand its structure?

Comment: I can - but is that germane to the  question?  I thought the important information to convey was that it's nested, unknown depth, and the initial key:value pairs are not part of a nested array but are the top level in the array.  I understand the example won't pass JSON validation, but it was meant as an illustration.

Comment: Right now it has the illusion of being nested, but actually `Array1`, `Array2`, etc. are all members of the top level object. I'm not sure if that's intended. In an algorithm that isn't hardcoded for much structure, it's important that we know what structures are optional or not.

Comment: Why don't you use this: json_decode($object, true);

Comment: @Mojtaba - I am using json_decode to convert the object to $data1 array, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "table"? A HTML table display? A database table? If the latter: are you supposed to execute `create table` statements?

Comment: @ryan - the updated JSON validated data works perfectly as test data.

Comment: @trincot - mysql table, sorry, I should have been clearer on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT after all the comments and exchanges. I'll take your example to be more precise

```
<?php

$inputJson = '{                         
   "Key1": "Value1",                      
   "Key2": "Value2",                      
   "Key3": "Value3",                                 
   "Table1": [],                      
   "Table2": [{                      
      "Key1": "Value1",                  
      "Key2": "Value2",                  
      "Key3": "Value3"},
     {
        "Key1": "Value1",                  
        "Key2": "Value2",                  
        "Key3": "Value3"}],
   "Table3": [{
        "Key1": "Value1",                  
        "Key2": "Value2",                  
        "Key3": "Value3"},
         {
           "Table4": [{
              "Key1": "Value1",              
              "Key2": "Value2",              
              "Key3": "Value3"},
           {
              "Table5": [{
                 "Key1": "Value1",          
                 "Key2": "Value2",          
                 "Key3": "Value3"}]
             }]
       }]    
 }';
```

So The input is the same as you, then here is the recursive function

```
function toto(array $input, $tableName = '')
{
    foreach ($input as $key => $element) {
        if (is_array($element)) {
            // if key is integer its the first level of array so we keep the $tablename - edited part
            $key = is_int($key) ? $tableName : $key;
            toto($element, $key);
        } else {
            if ($tableName === '') {
                $tableName = 'NonNestedTableName';
            }
            echo "TableName: $tableName, Key: $key, Data: $element \n";
        }
    }
}

$inputArray = json_decode($inputJson, true);

toto($inputArray);
```

This will display

> TableName: NonNestedTableName, Key: Key1, Data: Value1
>
> TableName: NonNestedTableName, Key: Key2, Data: Value2
>
> TableName: NonNestedTableName, Key: Key3, Data: Value3
>
> TableName: Table2, Key: Key1, Data: Value1
>
> TableName: Table2, Key: Key2, Data: Value2
>
> TableName: Table2, Key: Key3, Data: Value3
>
> TableName: Table2, Key: Key1, Data: Value1
>
> TableName: Table2, Key: Key2, Data: Value2
>
> TableName: Table2, Key: Key3, Data: Value3
>
> TableName: Table3, Key: Key1, Data: Value1
>
> TableName: Table3, Key: Key2, Data: Value2
>
> TableName: Table3, Key: Key3, Data: Value3
>
> TableName: Table4, Key: Key1, Data: Value1
>
> TableName: Table4, Key: Key2, Data: Value2
>
> TableName: Table4, Key: Key3, Data: Value3
>
> TableName: Table5, Key: Key1, Data: Value1
>
> TableName: Table5, Key: Key2, Data: Value2
>
> TableName: Table5, Key: Key3, Data: Value3

Comment: so VERY close...  except that, using your example, the table name for nested the arrays needs to be the array key, i.e. level1, level11, etc. instead of the index number.  thank you!

Comment: What is wrong with that? What should be the tableName for key11 and key12?

Comment: Ok, not sure to understand. Please tell exactly me what tableName are you expecting for value11, value12.

Comment: Instead of the index, the table name needs to be set to the array name, so for  "level1" => [
      "key11" => "value11",
      "key12" => "value12",  the table name would be "level1", fieldname1="key11", datafield1="value11"; fieldname2="key12", datafield2 ="value12".  In practice "level1" might be "Customer": [ "name": "john", "address": "123 Main Street"] .. so this needs to go to the Customer table.

Comment: Yes, but if you look at my output its the cas `TableName: level1, Key: key11, Data: value11` and same tableName for value12. So its exactly what you wrote in the previius comment

Comment: Or you means you need echo/insert all the values (value11 and value12) for a nested array in the same echo/insert? In one shot?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected queries for each nested level then we will adjust my scripr

Comment: Edited my question and your post also to clairify.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I'm noob and didn't know that.  appreciate the help.

Comment: @Scubadiver check my updated answer. I think we get it for good ;)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try `json_decode` to turn the JSON string into an array. It does take care of nested levels as well.

Give it a try: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Yeah, but what do you do once you have the array? That's the whole point of this question!